# Can't grab POST data with C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

have a page that posts form data to a C# page using jQuery:

```
  $('#AskMe').click(function () {
            var question = $("#meQuestion").val();

            if (question != "") {
                conversation.push({ "role": "user", "content": question });
                isLoading(1);
                $.post("ajax/chat/response_chat.aspx", { messages: conversation }, function (data) {
                    isLoading(0);
                    refreshQuota();
                });
                
            } else {

            }
        });
```

In the receiving page, for some reason I can't get access to the data? I see it, but can get it out for some reason? I have used multiple ways to try to get to it, but nothing works?

```
               // var _messages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.Form["messages"]);
                var _messages = Request.Form["messages"];
                // var test = _messages["messages"];

                JObject test = JObject.Parse(Request.Form["messages"]);
                JArray testArray = (JArray)_messages[test];  

                var _messages2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Params["messages"]);
                var _messages3 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Form["messages"]);
                var _messages4 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request["messages"]);
```

In the Request.Form variable (just used mumbo jumbo for testing):

```
Request.Form = {messages%5b0%5d%5brole%5d=user&messages%5b0%5d%5bcontent%5d=some+test&messages%5b1%5d%5brole%5d=user&messages%5b1%5d%5bcontent%5d=sgergser+e}
```

Comment: Would you try with `{ messages: JSON.stringify(conversation) }` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I see it"? What do you see where?

Comment: When you see it, what does it look like?

Comment: Can you get the messages using 

`var messagesJson = Request.Form["messages"];`
`var messages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(messagesJson);`

Comment: @OnePage this did the trick. Please post as answer and I'll acknowledge it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer from comment which worked for him

> Would you try with { messages: JSON.stringify(conversation) } ?